# How to get values from a hash within an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, jruby

I have an array consisting of multiple hashes with the same structures. I also have another array filled with strings:

```
prop_array = [
                {:name=>"item1", :owner=>"block1",:ID=>"11"},
                {:name=>"item2", :owner=>"block2",:ID=>"22"},
                {:name=>"item3", :owner=>"block3",:ID=>"33"},
                {:name=>"item4", :owner=>"block4",:ID=>"44"}
            ]


owner_array = ["block1","block2","block3","block4"]
```

I want to check if any of the `:owner` values in the hash matches with any of the strings in `owner_array` and set the variable `:partID` to the `:ID` value:

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
owner_array.each do |owner|
    prop_array.each do |prop|
        prop.each do |key, value|
            if key[:owner] == owner.to_s
                puts "YES"
                partID = key[:ID]
                puts partID
            end
        end
    end
end
```

If this ran correctly `partID` should be returned:

```
=> "11"
=> "22"
=> "33"
=> "44"
```

Comment: If given prop_array and owner_array what should be the result of your computation? You will have four matches in your example,

Comment: would you mind to clarify what `set the variable ":partID" to that ':ID' value` means?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What does "set the variable ":partID" to the ':ID' value" mean? `:partID` is not a valid name for a variable. Also, what does "doesn't work" mean? In what way doesn't it work? Is there an error message? If yes, what is the precise text of the error message, and which line does it refer to? Are you expecting different output? What output do you expect and why? What output do you get instead? Do you have any idea why? Also, what does this have to do with [tag:jruby]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to check if the any of the ':owner' value in the hash matches
>   with any of the strings in owner_array

```
prop_array.select {|hash| owner_array.include?(hash[:owner]) }
#=> [{:name=>"item1", :owner=>"block1", :ID=>"11"}, {:name=>"item2", :owner=>"block2", :ID=>"22"}, {:name=>"item3", :owner=>"block3", :ID=>"33"}, {:name=>"item4", :owner=>"block4", :ID=>"44"}]
```

> set the variable ":partID" to that ':ID' value

```
 partID = prop_array.select { |hash| owner_array.include?(hash[:owner]) }
                    .map    { |hash| hash[:ID] }
 #=> ["11", "22", "33", "44"]
```

## EDIT

Since you want these values to assign in a loop, go with:

```
partID = prop_array.select { |hash| owner_array.include?(hash[:owner]) }.each do |hash|
  # assignment happens here one by one
  cell_id = hash[:ID] # or whatever logic you have to assign this ID to cell
end
```

Comment: I want to store that value inside a cell in spreadsheet gem for ruby. Would that be possible?

Comment: your method works but it returns it as an array, I need a single value to store the data.

Comment: @danynl you asked for 4 values in your question - I showed you how. Can you specify what can be improved?

Comment: basically I only need one single value at a time, so I can insert that value into a cell in an excel file using the spreadsheet gem. I edited the question so it should make more sense now

Comment: @danynl it was not clear from the first question. It is not welcomed on SO to alter the question after the comments appear or answers are provided. Just iterate over the array and assign it to cels one at a time. Or better, see my edit in 20 seconds

Comment: @danynl what you're doing is forbidden on this site. You asked a question. I asnwered it. You edited the question, I edited my answer. You edited it again, and I again edited the answer. Now you changed the question in fourth time and this is not appropriate. You should accept the answer I have given to previous 3 forms of your question and go ask a new one. But make sure to make it clear next time ;)

Comment: yea sorry about that, I had to make it easier to understand by simplifying the original question. But your solutions seem to work, thank you.

Comment: @danynl no probs, it's just that sometimes oversimplifying leads to misunderstandings :)